# Как добавить папку на гитхаб?

Tags: git, github

Создал на гитхабе новый репозиторий, в гите пишу:

```
git init
git add .
git status (что бы посмотреть добавилось или нет)
```

и после этой команды мне пишет

> On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: Это означает, что у вас чистый рабочий каталог, другими словами — в нём нет отслеживаемых изменённых файлов. Git также не обнаружил неотслеживаемых файлов, в противном случае они бы были перечислены здесь.

Comment: а что надо сделать,чтобы гит обнаружил файлы?В моей папке,которую я хочу залить есть 8 файлов.

Comment: Закоммитить изменения нужно: `git commit -m "Описание Вашего коммита"`. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы создали через GitHub, то `git init`, если я правильно помню, можно заменить `git clone`.